# Unable to execute lightning sample test for non-Chrome browser

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx, lightning-testing-service

So, I've never done this before, so I beg a pardon if the answer is quite obvious.

I wanna dive into lightning testing service, but I've faced the following problem at the very beginning.

So, after successful `sfdx force:lightning:test:install`, I'm trying to perform `sfdx force:lightning:test:run -a jasmineTests.app`, but it's failed with the error:

```
ERROR:  Something went wrong with the test run. It might be an environmental or configuration issue.
Error Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 38 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-A8DCCM6', ip: '172.16.1.33', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver.
```

So, I see, it's unsuccessfully trying to find Chrome on my PC. But I don't use it, but Firefox and Vivaldi. 
Have I download it or there are better options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lightning Testing Service uses a "headless" web browser to drive the execution of your JavaScript tests in a real browser environment. It uses ChromeDriver to do that, so Chrome has to be available in order to run `sfdx force:lightning:test:run`.

You can actually run the test suites yourself in another web browser by opening the test runner Lightning app directly within your scratch org. Remember that LTS *must* be run in a scratch org as LTS tests are not isolated in test context and can leave side effects behind.

LTS's dependencies aren't very well documented; I'm not aware of any way to have it run on another browser in headless, CLI mode. You don't have to use Chrome to view the test results, however, as the SFDX command will display them on the command line.

As an additional consequence, if you choose to run LTS tests in a continuous integration pipeline, your container environment must have a web browser available.